# Overflow a list inside a div of which overflow:hidden

Tags: css, list, overflow

I have a div and that div has a height of 200px. Inside the div there is text and I don't want the div to have scrollbars therefore I've set overflow:hidden.

Now, inside that div there is a also a list, acting as a dropdown box. When you click on the list/dropdown box, I want it to come on TOP of the main div.

Here is an example with the main div to overflow:hidden:

[image]

And this is an example without overflow:hidden. So I want the following but the text not overflowing.

[image]

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w8kQA/

Comment: It's already positioned absolute...

Comment: Is it important to use the dropdown list inside this box? What do you think about the dropdown with absolute position , but not inside in this box?

Comment: Well that is not possible. If I tell you I have 20 boxes inside the div? It's a settings panel. It is not possible by any chance to be outside the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the overflow:hidden on the element inside the box, instead of on the box itself:

http://jsfiddle.net/w8kQA/1/

Comment: Nice answer. You could change height to `height: inherit` in `p` to encapsulate it a bit more. This would require that you change list to `position: absolute` though: http://jsfiddle.net/w8kQA/5/

Comment: All jsfiddles in this question are dead, answer should be revised.

Answer (score 0):

In the comments above, you mention that you have 20 boxes inside a div.

If that is the case then I would wrap the `#box` and the `.list` inside of a `holder` div. That way you can achive your layout and still have multiple boxes in a div.

**JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w8kQA/2/**

Comment: I prefer your answer on ptriek's comment so

Comment: No problem :) I prefered his answer to mine so I just added a small improvement to it

Answer (score -1):

You can also reduce the max-height of your list to fit into the div. 
http://jsfiddle.net/etienne_carre/w8kQA/4/