# Allow specific tag to override overflow:hidden

Tags: html, css

I've got a `<div>`, that's a certain `height` and `width`, and `overflow:hidden` so that specific inner images are clipped; however I want one image in the `<div>` to pop out of the border (i.e. to override the `overflow:hidden`). How do I do this?

Comment: Almost identical question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8432883/overflow-a-list-inside-a-div-of-which-overflowhidden

Comment: @Lisa I agree, I wish there was a way to exclude an element from any overflow!

Comment: and now I am truly stuck, because I can't use absolute positioning and overflow is clipping my form!

Answer (score 132):

The trick is to keep the `overflow:hidden` element with `position:static` and position the overflowing element relative to a higher parent (rather than the `overflow:hidden` parent). Like so:

```css
.relative-wrap {
    /*relative on second parent*/
    position: relative;
}

.overflow-wrap {
    height: 250px;
    width: 250px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: lightblue;
    
    /*no relative on immediate parent*/
}

.respect-overflow {
    position: relative;
    top: 75px;
    left: 225px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background: green;    
}
.no-overflow {
    position: absolute;
    top: 150px;
    left: 225px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="relative-wrap">
    
    <div class="overflow-wrap">
        
        <div class="respect-overflow">
        
        </div>
        <div class="no-overflow">
            
        </div>
        
    </div>
    
</div>
```

I also want to note, a very common use case for the desire to have an element overflow its container in this way is when you want animate the height of a dropdown or container from X to 0, and therefore need to have `overflow: hidden` on the container. Usually you have something *inside* the container that you want to overflow regardless. Since these elements are only accessibly when the container is "open", you can take advantage and set the overflow back to `visible`  *after* the container is fully open, and then set it back to `hidden` before trying to animate the container back to `height: 0`.

Comment: Why do you mention `position: static` in your text and then not use it in code?

Comment: position: static is the default. You can set it on .overflow-wrap if you have something overriding the default

Comment: Wonderful solution, works like magic. And so simple.

Comment: There may be a better way, but in the context of animating a dropdown and setting `overflow: visible` after the element opens you can use a setTimeout function (you will also have to know/control the transition-duration css property also)
`setTimeout(() => { collapseElement.dataset.state = 'open' }, transitionDuration);`
Where in css `[data-state="open"] { overflow: visible }`

Answer (score 24):

I know this is an old post, but this can be done (at least in Chrome).  I figured this out about two years ago and it's saved me a couple times.

Set the child to have position of fixed and use margins instead of top and left to position it.

```css
#wrapper {
    width: 5px;
    height: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#parent {
    position: relative;
}

button {
    position: fixed;
    margin: 10px 0px 0px 30px;
}
```

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/senica/Cupmb/

Comment: Hey this seems to work great in Chrome, Firefox and Safari - I'll try it out in IE. Thanks for the hack.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work in IE (version 10). It would have been really neat.

Comment: nice, but if you set position:fixed, it will be fixed - the button will stay on the same place while scrolling the page...

Comment: This doesn't seem to work if `#wrapper` has a `transform` set

Comment: It wouldnt because transforms create their own stacking context

Answer (score 19):

Wrap your `overflow: hidden` `div` with another `div` that has a css property of  -

`transform: translate(0, 0);`

and in your specific tag that you want it to override the  - `overflow: hidden` , set it with  -

`position: fixed;`  it will continue to be position relatively to its parent

i.e  -

```css
.section {
    /* ... */
    transform: translate(0, 0);
}

.not-hidden {
   /* ... */
   position: fixed;
}
```

**[See the fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/urielz/upj89rqo/)**

Comment: WOW is this brilliant, however for different reasons. You do not actually need the transform and you can change position fixed to absolute. Rather the actual way this works is by the simple fact that an element is clipped in accordance to the ancestor to which it is positioned by which is not necessarily always the parent element in the case of position absolute in fixed where the element is instead positioned to the nearest position relative. Thus, you can have (an) element(s) in between relative and absolute that is overflow hidden.

Comment: Yes looks good - simpler demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/2esvjh4p/

Comment: Amazing, it works! @JackG Didn't work for me without `position: fixed` or without transform if you have a `position: relative` parent.

Answer (score 14):

All given answers where not satisfying for me.
They are all hackish in my opinion and difficult to implement in complex layouts.

So here is a simple solution:

*Once a parent has a certain overflow, there is no way to let its children override this.*

If a child needs to override the parent overflow, then a child can have a different overflow than the other children.

So **define** the **overflow on each child** **instead of** declaring it on the **parent**:

```
<div class="panel">
    <div class="outer">
        <div class="inner" style="background-color: red;">
            <div>
                title
            </div>

            <div>                     
                some content
            </div>
        </div>    
    </div>  
</div>

.outer {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}    

.outer:hover {
    overflow: visible;
}  

.inner:hover {
    position: absolute;
}
```

Here is a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/ryojeg1b/1/

Comment: sadly not appropriate for e.g. scrollable containers

Answer (score 8):

You cannot, unless you change your HTML layout and move that image out of the parent div. A little more context would help you find an acceptable solution.

Answer (score 4):

All the above is nice but nothing beats `JAVASCRIPT`.
(Using `jquery`).
So,

```
<script>
var element = $('#myID');
var pos = element.offset();
var height = element.height(); // optional
element.appendTo($('body')); // optional
element.css({
    position : 'fixed'
}).offset(pos).height(height);
</script>
```

What I do is, get the original position of the element (relative to the page), optionally get the height or width, optionally append the element to the body, apply the new css rule `position : fixed` and finally apply the original position and optionally width and height.

Comment: I don't normally downvote people, but I just gota downvote this. This is a flat out terrible approach to web page programming. Coding gurus at Google and Mozilla spend eternity perfecting the SIMID driven CSS internals. You simply cannot beat just letting the browser do the work. Instead of going all javascript, you should move as much of the processing as possible to the CSS. Doing so is, because of the reasons listed above, the best approach to webpage programming. Also, don't use JQuery.

Comment: No hard feelings. Opinions are like noses. Everyone has one. IMHO it is just another way to solve the problem. JQuery is just that. Another way to solve problems. Happy new year.

Comment: I will +1 because it's a solution to a problem that in some circumstances does not have a solution.  Obviously when the "coding gurus" at Google and Mozilla give us a CSS solution this one will no longer be needed.  (That said, I will avoid using it.)

Comment: This solution can be handy when you don't have full control over existing HTML and CSS (e.g. you're making a dropdown plugin). One tweak -- if you set `position: absolute` (instead of fixed), it has the same effect but also works when the user scrolls the page.

Comment: I'll also +1 @SMX 's comment.  using this technique in a wordpress plugin can be very handy when you don't have access or even know parent elements.

Comment: Although I don't love this solution, it is the most suitable for my context since I really don't have any control over the parent elements on the page. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can do that by wrapping the 'overflow:hidden' div in another div.
Example:

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <img src="img1" alt="">
  </div> 
  <img src="img2" alt="">
</div>

.outer, .inner{
   position:relative;
}

.inner{
  overflow:hidden;
}

img{
  position:absolute;
}
```

In the above example all the elements inside the div with class of 'inner' will be affected by 'overflow:hidden'. Where as the images placed outside the inner div will be free to move out of boundaries.

This way we can make certain images pop out of the inner div.

Answer (score 2):

You can overflow an element out of the div by wrapping it in another div, then set your image as position:absolute; and offset it using margins.

```
<div class="no-overflow">
<div>
<img class="escape" src="wherever.jpg" />
</div>
</div>

.no-overflow{
overflow:hidden;
width: 500px
height: 100px
}

.escape{
position: absolute;
margin-bottom: -150px;
}
```

Example (tested in firefox + IE10) http://jsfiddle.net/Ps76J/

Comment: **Note:** This solution will not work if any of the elements within the element with `overflow: hidden` applied have a position assigned, e.g. `.no-overflow > div { position: relative; }`

Answer (score 2):

There is currently no way I am aware of to make a parent node with overflow hidden have children visible outside it (with the exception of `position:fixed` children).

HOWEVER, it is possible to instead of using overflow, you can just use the outline property set to the color of the background combined with the z-index property to mask some elements while retaining others like so.

```css
.persuado-overflow-hidden {
 /*gives the appearance of overflow:hidden*/
  z-index: -100;
  position: relative;
  outline: 1000vw solid white;
  overflow: visible;
}
.overridevisible {
/*takes the element out of the persuado overflow hidden*/
  z-index: 1;
}
/*does the other styling to the text*/
.loremcontainer {
  width: 60vw;
  height: 60vh;
  margin: 20vw;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.loremtxt {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: -20vh;
  z-index: -1;
}
.positionmessage {
  z-index: 100;
  position: absolute;
  top: -12vh;
  left: -5vw;
  right: -5vw;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="persuado-overflow-hidden loremcontainer">
<div class="loremtxt">
<div class="overridevisible positionmessage">Then, theres this text outside the paragraphs inside the persuado overflow:hidden element</div>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce porta lorem lorem, eu dapibus libero laoreet et. Fusce finibus, felis ac condimentum commodo, mauris felis dictum sapien, pellentesque tincidunt dui dolor id nulla. Etiam vulputate turpis eu lectus ornare, in condimentum purus feugiat. Donec ultricies lacinia urna, sit amet ultrices magna accumsan ut. Suspendisse potenti. Maecenas nisl nibh, accumsan vel sodales in, rutrum at sem. Suspendisse elit urna, luctus vitae urna ut, convallis ultricies tellus. Ut aliquet auctor neque, nec ullamcorper tortor ullamcorper vitae. Fusce at pharetra ante. Aliquam sollicitudin id ante sit amet sagittis. Suspendisse id neque quis nisi mattis vulputate. Donec sollicitudin pharetra tempus. Integer congue leo mi, et fermentum massa malesuada nec.
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

overflow refers to the container not allowing oversized content to be displayed (when set to hidden). It's got nothing to do with inner elements that can have overflow:whatever, and still wont' be displayed.

Answer (score -2):

Z-index doesnt seem to work, but here I have a workaround which worked fine for me, as I needed overflow only to be "visible" when hovering a child element:

```
#parent {
   overflow: hidden;
}

#parent:hover {
   overflow: visible;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question... at all.

Answer (score -3):

I've got a super-easy solution to this problem: Use the "pre" tag.
I know the pre tag is the equivalent of using "goto" in programming, but hey: it works!

```html
<div style="overflow: hidden; width: 200px;">
  <pre style="overflow: auto;">
    super long text which just goes on and on and on and on and one, etc.
  </pre>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't remotely work. If you run the code snippet the only reason you can see all the text is that the div is wider than the content. If you set `width: 200px` on the div, the content inside the pre tag will get cut off as expected by the `overflow: hidden` property.

Comment: My apologies, I forgot to add a “style” attribute to the “pre” tag. Now the scroll-bar will appear.
I wonder if I am miss-understanding the OP’s question?  I thought the problem was: there’s an outer element with “overflow: hidden” but an inner element needs to not wrap.  The “pre” tag allows this to happen.  If an image is placed inside the “pre” tag, the entire image will display (you still need to use the scroll-bar); without the “pre” tag, the image will be chopped (you cannot see the entire image).

Comment: But now I think the OP was actually asking about can an inner element “escape” and extend beyond the boundaries of the outer element… in-which case the “pre” tag solution will not work.  But remember, the “pre” tag solution does allow the entire contains to be viewed instead of chopped (which is hopefully an acceptable solution).  Thanks.

Comment: As a side note, we use this solution when two very long lines of text need to be compared to each other (visually, by a human).  When a line of text wraps, it is very difficult to compare it with another.  Angular Material has containers with “overflow: hidden” and the “pre” solution was the only thing which worked for us.

Comment: If I understand what you're trying to achieve with this, wouldn't `white-space: nowrap;` achieve the same thing without unnecessarily rendering text in monospace font?

Comment: Yes; well I guess technically the correct thing would be: "white-space: pre;" (to preserve white-space if desired). (BTW I'm surprised how much css can be applied to PRE ... it's not as barren as I thought).