# Hovered element to overflow out from an overflow:hidden element css

Tags: css

I have made a fiddle for reference: http://jsfiddle.net/kLFn9/

The `overflow:hidden` in question is highlighted.

Basically, i'm using `:hover:after` to show a tool tip. but the parent element has `overflow: hidden` on it. How can i force the element hovered to escape the parent element?

Relevant CSS:

```css
div {
    width:500px;
    height:200px;
    background:red;   
    margin: 50px;
    overflow: hidden; /* this rule */
}

span:hover:after {
    content: attr(data-name); 
    color: black;
    position: absolute;
    top: -150px;;
    left: 0;   
}
```

Comment: To bypass `overflow:hidden`, you can trick it .. see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29687454/2165415

Comment: If you are okay with the span also popping out, it can be done: http://jsfiddle.net/h27a77j7/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no (easy) way to allow a child tag to override the effects of the `overflow:hidden` declaration on the parent div. See: [Allow specific tag to override overflow:hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8837050/allow-specific-tag-to-override-overflowhidden)

Your only possible recourse would be with javascript: first grab the span's offset relative to the document, then move it to another location in the DOM (i.e. direct child to the body), set its position to absolute, and use the offsets you grabbed to set its left and top properties, that would locate it at the same position within the document, but now it's not contained by the div, and so no longer needs to obey `overflow:hidden`.

Comment: As this is the only answer that seemed to understand what I was asking, correct!

Answer (score 9):

You can use `margin-top` and `padding-top`.

`padding-top` will extend your parent area, but a negative `margin-top` will keep it in the expected position.

It will look like you're escaping the overflow, but in fact you're not.

```css
div {
    width:500px;
    height:200px;
    background:red;
    margin: 50px;
    overflow: hidden; /* this rule */

    background-clip: content-box; /*use this to constrain the background color within the content-box and do not paint the padding */
    padding-top: 200px; /* space required to display the tooltip */
    margin-top: -150px; /*200px - 50px of the original margin*/
}
    
span {
 background: blue;
 color: white;
 position: relative;
 top:100px;  
 display:block;   
 width: 100px;  
 margin: auto;    
}
    
span:hover:after {
    content: attr(data-name); 
    color: black;
    position: absolute;
    top: -150px;;
    left: 0;   
}
```

```html
<div>
<span data-name="here">hover</span>
</div>
```

This may introduce pointer events problems, but you can fix them using `pointer-events` then.

Comment: When used with right and left for scrolling, my content didn’t stay in the box.  But this at least works vertically.

Answer (score 3):

I am using simple **z-index** for force the element hovered to escape the parent element. Please check

```css
div {
 width:500px;
height:200px;
 background:red;   
    margin: 50px;
    overflow: hidden; /* this rule */
}

span {
 background: blue;
color: white;
    position: relative;
 top:100px;  
display:block;   
width: 100px;  
margin: auto;    
}

span:hover:after {
 content: attr(data-name); 
color: black;
 position: fixed; /* Here I replaced position abosolute to fixed */
top: 10px;  /* Here I replaced top -150px  to 10px */
 left: 250px;  /* Here I replaced positionleft 0 to 250px */
 z-index:99999;} /* Here I added new z-index property to 99999 */
```

```html
<div>
<span data-name="here">hover</span>
</div>
```

Comment: This does work with `fixed` positioning but not with `absolute`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your trying to get at, but I recreated a tooltip framework for you to view. It's basically smoke and mirrors where I call :hover and the .class associated with it.

http://jsfiddle.net/WE8Dw/

Hope this helps.

Comment: "you can't pair up :before and :after tags with another :hover" Yes you can! That is valid CSS.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way using plain CSS to overflow a parent elements borders with a child, if it was set to `overflow:hidden;`. On possible CSS option is to use a sibling element to that one which has `overflow:hidden;` set and show that as popup.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases you can escape with `div{position: absolute;}`

Answer (score -1):

You can set child's position to fixed.