# Position own tooltip by css

Tags: html, css, tooltip

I want to create css based tooltips but I strugle with the correct position.
My idea is to set the tooltip text as a data-tooltip attribute and show them on hover.

The problem is now that in some circumstances the position is not working.
One case for example is, if the tooltip is overlapped by a relative positioned element with overflow hidden.

See this demonstrating fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/45Lbhusk/

```css
[data-tooltip1]:hover::before {
      content: attr(data-tooltip1);
      left:auto;
      position: fixed;
      margin-top: -1.5rem;
      background: lightgray;
      border: 1px solid black;
    }

    [data-tooltip2]:hover::before {
      content: attr(data-tooltip2);
      left:auto;
      position: absolute;
      margin-top: -1.5rem;
      background: lightgray;
      border: 1px solid black;
    }

    span{
      display: block;
      font-weight: bold;
      margin: 3px;
      padding: 10px;
      border: 1px solid blue;
    }

    div{
      overflow: hidden;
      position: relative;
      background: #eeeeee;
    }
```

```html
Some <br/>
    dummy <br/>
    text <br/>
    so <br/>
    that <br/>
    scrollbars <br/>
    appear. <br/>
     <br/> <br/>

    <div>
      <span data-tooltip1="Can you read this long text?">Hover for fixed positioned tooltip</span>
    </div>

    <br/>

    <div>
      <span data-tooltip2="Can you read this long text?">Hover for absolute positioned tooltip</span>
    </div>

     <br/> <br/>
    Some <br/>
    dummy <br/>
    text <br/>
    so <br/>
    that <br/>
    scrollbars <br/>
    appear. <br/>
```

I tried to position the tooltip "fixed" and "absolute" but both has problems:

- fixed is not scrolling and the tooltip is displayed on the wrong position if the page was scrolled
- absolute tooltips could get cut by the parent.

I read many other questions to the same topic but they require js to work or has other requirements. I really want to have a css only solution.

**Edit 1**: The other elements on the page could be generated from other scripts, like the jquery data tables plugin. So I cannot take care that other elements has to fit to the tooltip. The tooltip should work with all other elements. So please don't change the div styles because I'm not able to make sure that it fits to the tooltip.

Answer (score 4):

This solution aims to solve the `absolute` version of tooltip getting cut by a container with `overflow: hidden`.

It uses the method from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44893032/20436957) to display `absolute` positioned tooltip within a container set as `overflow: hidden`.

Additionally, this also added control for `pointer-events` so in a list of items, the tooltips are less likely to block hover events on other adjacent elements.

The down side, however, is that this method does require additional styling to extend the visible range of the container. This might very likely be contradict to the reasons it was set as `overflow: hidden` in the first place.

Example:

```css
[data-tooltip1]:hover::before {
  content: attr(data-tooltip1);
  left: auto;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -1.5rem;
  background: lightgray;
  border: 1px solid black;
}


[data-tooltip2]:hover::before {
  content: attr(data-tooltip2);
  left: auto;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -1.5rem;
  background: lightgray;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

span {
  display: block;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 3px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

div {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  background: #eeeeee;
  padding-top: 100px;
  margin-top: -100px;
  background-clip: content-box;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
Some <br />
dummy <br />
text <br />
so <br />
that <br />
scrollbars <br />
appear. <br />
<br />
<br />

<div>
  <span data-tooltip1="Can you read this long text?"
    >Hover for absolute positioned tooltip (this container has overflow: hidden)</span
  >
</div>

<br />

<div>
  <span data-tooltip2="Can you read this long text?"
    >Hover for absolute positioned tooltip (this container also has overflow: hidden)</span
  >
</div>

<br />
<br />
Some <br />
dummy <br />
text <br />
so <br />
that <br />
scrollbars <br />
appear. <br />
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I've updated the question because I cannot make sure the the page is running with the tooltip. The tooltip should run with the page.

Comment: @Sammy What do you mean by running with the page? I think this answer solves the question quite elegantly.

Comment: I mean that I don't have the control over all html elements. Like the jquery data table plugin which generates dynamically other html elements like a table and so. This solution works very well when I take care that all elements are designed in a way that the tooltips work. But I cannot guarantee that. The tooltips should work (that means, displayed at the correct position and not be cut by other elements) without taking care on all other elements.