# Bootstrap progressbar vertical marker with title

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, progress-bar

I want to create a marker on the prograssbar, that has a title, unfortunately the title doesn't show when I hover, however if I remove `position: relative;` from the parent element the title appears, but I can't position the marker. Anyone got any idea how to accomplish this?

Here is my current progress: http://www.bootply.com/qxNLC4y6VT

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add `overflow: visible;` to the `.progress` element the title should appear.
As it actually already appears, but the overflow was "cut off" by the border of the progress bar element =)

[**DEMO**](http://www.bootply.com/NOGEeTrRKI)

---

**Update:**
If you want to keep the border radius and hidden overflow, you need to position the element with the tooltip outside the `.progress` element ... e.g. wrap the whole thing in another container where you place also your red marker element.

[**DEMO**](http://www.bootply.com/CxzO7Hbv3e)

Comment: Oh, it works, but "cuts" the border-radius of the progress-bar. Is there any other way around this? (I can add border-radius to progress-bar I guess)

Comment: Hi @kviktor, I updated the answer ... unfortunately you can not choose which children are clipped by `overflow:hidden` ... so you will need to place the red marker element somewhere outside the `.progress` element, so that the tooltip can display and that you can keep the overflow settings. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8837050/allow-specific-tag-to-override-overflowhidden ... there are some hacks proposed =)

Comment: These demos aren't available anymore which negates the value of this answer a lot.