# z-index of bootstrap button dropdown

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having issues with the z-index of a bootstrap dropdown.

http://jonwhittlestone.com/public/z.html

[image: Portion of the page]

In this page, the pass button's associated dropdown is appearing on a lower layer that the container and appears to constrain it.

Editing the following doesn't seem to fix.

[image: Web inspector screenshot]

Any ideas CSS people?

Thanks

Jon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your dropdown isn't being shown is that this element has the CSS option of `overflow:hidden`:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
```

Edit `bootstrap-alizarin.css` line 4100 and remove `overflow:hidden`.

After you have done this, insert the following code after the closing tag of the `.sanctions-result-actions` div:

```
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

it is `overflow:hidden` issue make this changes of the `.panel`

`overflow:hidden` will not allow its children to show if are coming out

```
.panel-group .panel {
    background: #fbfbfb;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    border-radius: 5px;
    /* overflow: hidden; */ /* remove this */
    float: left; /* and add this */
    width: 100%; /* and add this */
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is other css style (bootstrap-alizarin.css:4100), you have to change it:

```
.panel-group .panel { 
    /*...*/
    overflow: hidden; /* to remove */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The rule `overflow: hidden` on the container is the problem

override it to `overflow: visible`

Answer (score 0):

I can see that a parent div with class="panel panel-default" has an overflow: hidden.
If you want to display the inner div out of it's parent overflow-hidden div, you must place this div out of the current one.
Check this post: [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8837050/allow-specific-tag-to-override-overflowhidden)