# Override ALL parent / grandparent / etc.... that have overflow:hidden and Witdh

Tags: html, css

I am facing a problem where I am using a JS controller that builds several html elements and I only have a tiny control on some child elements (I can build html on them).

Using the answer from the question 
[Allow specific tag to override overflow:hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8837050/allow-specific-tag-to-override-overflowhidden)

I have build a scenario of my problem (not only the father uses `overflow:hidden` but also the grandfather and great-grandfather, and so on.... and one of them is defining a lower `width:` than my child.... )

This [example](http://jsfiddle.net/98qgpzq6/3/) is when the grandfather has NO `width`.

This [example](http://jsfiddle.net/98qgpzq6/1/) is the actual code that is not working.... I **do NOT see the RED box**....and **I NEED to see it**....

Comment: You may be best writing some JS to either put the stuff you want in a higher level element in the first place or use it to move the element after has been added. Can't help more than that right now, will have a think about it though.

Comment: @Sarcoma, I was going to give you a "vote up" on your answer, for the effort you are putting on helping me.... but you deleted it......  Off note: man, your nickname is scary ;) change it hehehehe

Comment: ha, no it's fine, better keep things tidy, it's no help to people trying to find real answers. It's from a time when I was reading Alexander Solzhenitsyn's Cancer Ward, it just kind of stuck, plus no one else ever, ever has that username.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the page doesn't need to scroll this might work. It at least does what you have asked for, show the red box.

Adding `position: fixed;` to the element that you want to see breaks `overflow: hidden;`.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/98qgpzq6/6/)

This works because fixed elements are contained by the viewport.

[W3 CSS Position Fixed](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-positioning/#fixed-pos)

Comment: Great thanks, will that work for you? Bit of a weird fix.

Answer (score 0):

This not possible with pure CSS since the `width` in the top element is using `px`. You can however try to use `width: auto;`