# apply css styles to make the text fully visible

Tags: html, css, z-index, margin

Is it possible to apply css styles to the `inner` class in this case so that the text is fully displayed (inner div is wider than it's parent).

HTML:

```
<div class="main">
  <div>
    1111111
  </div>
  <div class="inner">
    dds adg asdg asdg
  </div>
  <div>
    22222
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.main {
  border:1px solid red;
  width: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.inner{
  height: 40px;
  border:2px solid green;
  margin-right: -10px;
}
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4km3e7y0/)

So, any changes for `.inner` (height: 40px should NOT be changed) so that the text is **fully** displayed in two lines by making that div a bit wider to the right?

Changing the html structure or CSS styles for main class are not allowed.

Unfortunately, scroll is not allowed.
Everything should look the same, but the inner div display text in two lines (inner div to look wider).

Comment: your main is set to 50px so it can't get wider than that. you can add an overflow:scroll to the .inner class

Comment: `overflow: hidden` cuts any content that flows outside of the outer elements dimensions. If you don’t want that effect, then don’t set overflow to hidden.

Comment: Tried `overflow: visible` ?

Comment: just remove the overflow from main and add a width to your .inner

Comment: Guys, please take a look here before downvoting:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8837050/allow-specific-tag-to-override-overflowhidden    Overflow:hidden for parent still possible.

Comment: Setting `overflow: auto` only will still collapse text, you'd need to set a bigger negative `margin-right` (like -50px) on the div.  https://jsfiddle.net/4km3e7y0/1/

Comment: Unfortunately, scroll is not an option for this task. I will mention it in the question.

Comment: That example you share still requires HTML structural changes and also CSS tweaks.

Comment: If I know the solution I won't ask this question. I'm sure it requires CSS tweaks. The question was if it is possible (I bet it is).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry if this doesn't comply with all your requirements but it's as far as I got bearing the example you shared, hope it helps.

```css
.relative-wrap {
    position: relative;
}
.main {
  border:1px solid red;
  width: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 80px;
}
.inner{
  height: 40px;
  border:2px solid green;
  margin-right: -50px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  background: white;
}
.textdown {
  line-height: 110px;
}
```

```html
<div class="relative-wrap">
  <div class="main">
    <div>
      1111111
    </div>
    <div class="inner">
      dds adg asdg asdg
    </div>
    <div class="textdown">
      22222
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You *have* to add `overflow-x: scroll;` or `auto` to the main element, and a fixed width to the child. I can think of no way to do it with only changing the CSS for `inner`:

https://jsfiddle.net/66uqoLy0/1/