# Tooltip Getting Cut Off With Overflow: Hidden Parent

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a tooltip `div` that is inside a parent with `overflow: hidden` so when the tooltip has a lot of text it gets cut off because the parent is not large. The tooltip is `position: absolute`.

I've seen a lot of answers ([such as this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8837050/allow-specific-tag-to-override-overflowhidden)) that say the immediate parent that has the `overflow: hidden` should not be positioned. And then a higher up parent which has `overflow: visible` should be where the `position: relative` is placed.

The problem is I'm creating a generic tooltip component in Angular 2 and each one is positioned relative to a table header cell. So if I make the parent of the parent `position: relative`, then all the tooltips will be positioned relative to the table container instead of the table header cells. Anyone know how to fix the tooltip cutoff a different way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move your tooltip to the `<body>` and get the position of the hovered/clicked element by calling the [`getBoundingClientRect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) method which returns the position of the item relative to the body.
This way your tooltip can be really generic.

Worth mentioning that the method returns with an object that also contains the width and height which could be handy positioning the tooltip relative to the element.