# Show tooltip over overflow:hidden

Tags: css, tooltip, overflow

I want to show tooltips next to items in a rather complex editor with custom scrolling. The tooltips should "escape" the container that has `overflow: hidden` set to limit the viewport.

Here is an example that shows the problem:

```css
.container {
  border: 1px black solid;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.inner {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
}

.column {
  background-color: #99FF99;
  padding: 25px;
}

.tooltip-container {
  position: relative;
}

.content {
  background-color: #9999FF;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.tooltip {
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: #FF9999;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0%;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.tooltip-container:hover .tooltip {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner" id="inner" style="margin-left: -40px; margin-top: -40px">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column">
        <div class="tooltip-container">
          <div class="content">
            1
          </div>
          <div class="tooltip">
            Super nice and awesome and cool and hot 1
          </div>
        </div>    
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <div class="tooltip-container">
          <div class="content">
            2
          </div>
          <div class="tooltip">
            Super nice and awesome and cool and hot 2
          </div>
        </div>    
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <div class="tooltip-container">
          <div class="content">
            4
          </div>
          <div class="tooltip">
            Super nice and awesome and cool and hot 4
          </div>
        </div>    
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column">
        <div class="tooltip-container">
          <div class="content">
            3
          </div>
          <div class="tooltip">
            Super nice and awesome and cool and hot 3
          </div>
        </div>    
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <div class="tooltip-container">
          <div class="content">
            5
          </div>
          <div class="tooltip">
            Super nice and awesome and cool and hot 5
          </div>
        </div>    
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <div class="tooltip-container">
          <div class="content">
            6
          </div>
          <div class="tooltip">
            Super nice and awesome and cool and hot 6
          </div>
        </div>    
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column">
        <div class="tooltip-container">
          <div class="content">
            7
          </div>
          <div class="tooltip">
            Super nice and awesome and cool and hot 7
          </div>
        </div>    
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <div class="tooltip-container">
          <div class="content">
            8
          </div>
          <div class="tooltip">
            Super nice and awesome and cool and hot 8
          </div>
        </div>    
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <div class="tooltip-container">
          <div class="content">
            9
          </div>
          <div class="tooltip">
            Super nice and awesome and cool and hot 9
          </div>
        </div>    
      </div>
    </div>  
  </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7j1rvxbc/)

Of course I searched for the problem and there are a lot solutions to the problem already. However I did not find one that solves my problem

The most cited solution is to make the tooltip `position: absolute` and add a wrapper outside of the div with `overflow:hidden` as can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8837050/allow-specific-tag-to-override-overflowhidden). This does not work in my case because the tooltip should be to the right of the item it describes. So I need the relative position on the tooltip container.

I tried wrapping the tooltip with `position:relative` and some offset in a wrapper with `position:absolute`. This did not work, as the wrapper catches the mouse hover for the tooltip. Also this means I have to know the size of the attached item.

I tried laying out the items in the `tooltip-container` horizontally and then use the standard `position:absolute` trick, but I could not make that work either.

Does anybody have an idea?

Constraints:

- the tooltip appears in a container which has `overflow:hidden` and should escape it
- the content in the container can be moved around
- there are no fixed sizes
- if possible it should be a CSS only solution (but most definitely no jQuery)
- the tooltip should appear to the right of the attached item (bonus points if it can appear to any side of the item)
- the tooltip may not only contain text but also other controls and inputs

Comment: it cannot escape a container with overflow hidden - that is the point of hiding the overflow

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/popping-hidden-overflow/

Comment: @VXp That is the mentioned solution that does not work, where there is a `position:relative` wrapper around the `overflow:hidden`-div

Comment: @Pete I know. But maybe I can specify and exception to that rule. Or maybe there is a different possibility to clip certain children and others not.

Comment: Nope, the only thing you could do is have an outer container, containing two inner containers - one with overflow hidden, the other with your tool tips and then use a bit of js to position and show the tooltips depending on which element is hovered.  If you are wanting a pure css solution to this, then you are out of luck

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The only CSS trick you can use is the `position:fixed` that you block with a *null* transform and you can have most of your constraints:

```css
body {
  min-height:200vh;
  transform:translate(0,0);
}

.container {
  border: 1px black solid;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.inner {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
}

.column {
  background-color: #99FF99;
  padding: 25px;
}

.tooltip-container {
  position: relative;
}

.content {
  background-color: #9999FF;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.tooltip {
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: #FF9999;
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  transform:translate(50px,-50px);
  /*left: 100%;
  top: 0%;*/
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.tooltip-container:hover .tooltip {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner" id="inner" style="margin-left: -40px; margin-top: -40px">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column">
        <div class="tooltip-container">
          <div class="content">
            1
          </div>
          <div class="tooltip">
            Super nice and awesome and cool and hot 1
          </div>
        </div>    
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <div class="tooltip-container">
          <div class="content">
            2
          </div>
          <div class="tooltip">
            Super nice and awesome and cool and hot 2
          </div>
        </div>    
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <div class="tooltip-container">
          <div class="content">
            4
          </div>
          <div class="tooltip">
            Super nice and awesome and cool and hot 4
          </div>
        </div>    
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column">
        <div class="tooltip-container">
          <div class="content">
            3
          </div>
          <div class="tooltip">
            Super nice and awesome and cool and hot 3
          </div>
        </div>    
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <div class="tooltip-container">
          <div class="content">
            5
          </div>
          <div class="tooltip">
            Super nice and awesome and cool and hot 5
          </div>
        </div>    
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <div class="tooltip-container">
          <div class="content">
            6
          </div>
          <div class="tooltip">
            Super nice and awesome and cool and hot 6
          </div>
        </div>    
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column">
        <div class="tooltip-container">
          <div class="content">
            7
          </div>
          <div class="tooltip">
            Super nice and awesome and cool and hot 7
          </div>
        </div>    
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <div class="tooltip-container">
          <div class="content">
            8
          </div>
          <div class="tooltip">
            Super nice and awesome and cool and hot 8
          </div>
        </div>    
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <div class="tooltip-container">
          <div class="content">
            9
          </div>
          <div class="tooltip">
            Super nice and awesome and cool and hot 9
          </div>
        </div>    
      </div>
    </div>  
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That comes pretty close to what I need. Thanks. I will have to play and try it out a bit, but it looks promising

Comment: @jsf simply pay attention to never use top/left and only rely on transform or margin to move the element from it's intial position ... top/left will refer to the screen

Comment: Thanks. This solution does not fit all the constraints, but is the closest to what I need. I will have to find a workaround for the fixed size problem.

Comment: Dude I +1'ed you!
You saved my bacon!

I was creating react tabs and i needed a tooltip for each tab where they got squished and the labels would be elipses... but as soon as I would add the tooltips it would break the flex tabs where they would go off screen or the elipses wouldnt work. It is also hard to show a tooltip outside a overflow:hidden container. How does this work?? It was driving me crazy until I tried your display: flex solution and it worked like a charm!

Comment: Nice solution! Do any idea on how to workaround if .inner has set height and scroll?