# absolute div inside absolute div cuts off with respect to relative position

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have 3 divs on top of each other having following css.

```
.d1 {
    position: relative;
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.d2 {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: green;
    height: 25px;
    width: 50px;
}

.d3 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 83px;
}
```

and the divs that have classes are as follows:

```
<div class="d1">
  <div class="d2">
    <div class="d3">text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and as a result I see content of d3 cut off because of overflow:hidden in d1.

[image]

How can I avoid cut off content of d3 without modifying d1?

Comment: That's not possible. An `overflow: hidden` on a parent element will always hide overflowing children. There are other ways to get by this, but you have to restructure your HTML to achieve it.

Comment: Maybe this will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8837050/allow-specific-tag-to-override-overflowhidden

Comment: Make sure d3 is within bounds of d1, no? I mean set its width: `left: 83px; width: 17px;`

Answer (score 2):

### Getting around the overflow

An element can overflow from a `relative` or `absolute` positioned parent by setting its `position` to `fixed`. An element that has `position: fixed` will have the default `left`,`right`,`top`, and `bottom` styles set as `auto`. This will position `.d3` to the top-left of `.d2`, and then the `left: 83px` style will push it to the left from there.

### Making up the additional space

However, to get that additional movement to the right as the original markup, you will need to add `margin-left: 8px`, which will make-up the additional ~8px needed to replicate the original. Further adjustments to the position of `.d3` will need to be done by setting the `margin` style (*see below*).

### Your updated code should look like this

```css
.d1 {
   position: relative;
   background-color: yellow;
   height: 50px;
   width: 100px;
   overflow: hidden;
}

.d2 {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: green;
  height: 25px;
  width: 50px;
}

.d3 {
 position: fixed;
 margin-left: 8px;
 left: 83px;
}
```

```html
<div class="d1">
  <div class="d2">
    <div class="d3">text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Some considerations and caveats

As a previous commenter mentioned, best practice would be to fix your HTML markup because this solution could cause issues if you ever need to move the position of `.d3`. For example, setting `left`, `right`, `top`, or `bottom` will cause the default setting of this style, `auto`, from being unset, and the element will be positioned relative to the viewport rather than the parent `relative` or `absolute` element.