# Trying to make div appear on top of scrollable list of content but relative to list item

Tags: html, css, z-index

I have a list of items inside a div. The list is scrollable on the Y-axis but not the X-axis.

The end-goal is to have another div that will appear when clicked (context menu), it shall appear on top of and overflow/ignore the width restrictions of the div and it must be relative to the list item.

See the attached sample where a `#contextMenu` is hardcoded into list item 7.

The `#contextMenu` content is restricted by the X-axis width of the parent div, it should be on top of this.

```css
#parent {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
position: relative;

}

.listItem {
}

#contextMenu {
  z-index: 999;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid rgb(165, 165, 165);
  width: 200px;
  padding: 2px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <ul>
    <li class="listItem">List item 1</li>
    <li class="listItem">List item 2</li>
    <li class="listItem">List item 3</li>
    <li class="listItem">List item 4</li>
    <li class="listItem">List item 5</li>
    <li class="listItem">List item 6</li>
    <li class="listItem">List item 7
      <div id="contextMenu">
        <p> Menu item 1</p>
        <p> Menu item 2</p>
        <p> Menu item 3</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="listItem">List item 8</li>
    <li class="listItem">List item 9</li>
    <li class="listItem">List item 10</li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: Why did you set width:200px on your contextMenu. Do not set any width and this will fit your parent div.

Comment: @oguzhancerit I need it to not be restricted by the parent width

Comment: this answer will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29408237/2374549 and also there is an alternative method in here; https://codepen.io/agop/pen/itbew

Comment: @oguzhancerit thanks I had seen the 2nd one but not the first. Both useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `contextMenu` is a child element, it will always be relative to its parent's `z-index`. It remains nested. If I understand correctly, you want `contextMenu` to appear on top of the `#parent` div - this can't be accomplished while it's a child. Most likely you'll need to use javascript to create a new element on the list item's position when clicked.

Answer (score 1):

Presenting the solution I ended up with based on reasoning in accepted answer.

Removed `z-index` from context menu and the `position:relative;` from parent.
Move context menu to being sibling with the list.
Added JavaScript that on `mouseover` on a list item will change the CSS of the context menu to the list item top position.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // whenever we hover over a menu item that has a submenu
  // grab the menu item's position relative to its positioned parent

  $('.listItem').on('mouseover', function() {
    var menuItemPos = $(this).position();
    // place the menu in the correct position relevant to the menu item
    $("#contextMenu").css({
      top: menuItemPos.top,
      left: 120
    });
  });
});
```

```css
#parent {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.listItem {}

#contextMenu {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid rgb(165, 165, 165);
  width: 200px;
  padding: 2px;
  display: block;
  list-style-type: none;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
  <ul>
    <li class="listItem">List item 1</li>
    <li class="listItem">List item 2</li>
    <li class="listItem">List item 3</li>
    <li class="listItem">List item 4</li>
    <li class="listItem">List item 5</li>
    <li class="listItem">List item 6</li>
    <li id="listItem7" class="listItem">List item 7
    </li>
    <li class="listItem">List item 8</li>
    <li class="listItem">List item 9</li>
    <li class="listItem">List item 10</li>
  </ul>
  <div id="contextMenu">
    <p> Menu item 1</p>
    <p> Menu item 2</p>
    <p> Menu item 3</p>
  </div>

</div>
```