# Can you have a parent allow one absolutely positioned child to overflow and one to not overflow in React Native?

Tags: css, react-native, overflow

I have a parent element with 2 absolutely positioned children inside. I want one of the children's overflow to be visible and the other's overflow to be hidden. Like so:

[image: What I want]

Adding `overflow: 'hidden` to the parent hides the overflow of both the coin image and the 'most popular' sash but I want the coin image overflow to be visible.

```
container: {
    width: 155,
    height: 145,
    backgroundColor: Colours.white,
    borderRadius: 10,
    borderColor: Colours.borderTwo,
    borderWidth: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    margin: 10,
    marginBottom: 25,
    paddingBottom: 10,
    overflow: 'hidden',
  },
  mostPopularSash: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 2,
    right: -30,
    backgroundColor: Colours.yellow,
    width: 100,
    height: 40,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    transform: [{rotate: '40deg'}],
  },
  imageContainer: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: -22,
    width: 52,
    height: 52,
    borderRadius: 100,
    backgroundColor: Colours.white,
    borderColor: Colours.pageColour,
    borderWidth: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    shadowColor: '#171717',
    shadowOffset: {width: 0, height: 3},
    shadowOpacity: 0.2,
    shadowRadius: 2,
    elevation: 5,
  },
  image: {
    width: 40,
    height: 40,
  },
```

[image: What happens with above css]

I've tried adding `zIndex: 2` to the image container and then `zIndex: 1` to the parents parent but it didn't work..

Can't find much online to solve this problem as most queries related to 'overflow' are requesting the opposite effect.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manage to get the desired effect by wrapping the `container` that uses `overflow: 'hidden'` inside an outer container and then moving the `imageContainer` out of the `container` and into the outer container giving it `zIndex: 1` and keeping it absolutely positioned as well as giving it `alignSelf: 'center'`

Like so:

```
outerContainer: {
    width: '45%',
    margin: 10,
  },
  container: {
    height: 145,
    width: '100%',
    backgroundColor: Colours.white,
    borderRadius: 10,
    borderColor: Colours.borderTwo,
    borderWidth: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    marginBottom: 25,
    paddingBottom: 10,
    overflow: 'hidden',
  },
  mostPopularSash: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 2,
    right: -30,
    backgroundColor: Colours.yellow,
    width: 100,
    height: 40,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    transform: [{rotate: '40deg'}],
  },
  imageContainer: {
    zIndex: 1,
    position: 'absolute',
    top: -22,
    alignSelf: 'center',
    width: 52,
    height: 52,
    borderRadius: 100,
    backgroundColor: Colours.white,
    borderColor: Colours.pageColour,
    borderWidth: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    shadowColor: '#171717',
    shadowOffset: {width: 0, height: 3},
    shadowOpacity: 0.2,
    shadowRadius: 2,
    elevation: 5,
  },
  image: {
    width: 40,
    height: 40,
  },
```

```
<View style={styles.outerContainer}>
  <View style={styles.imageContainer}>
    <Image source={image} style={styles.image} />
  </View>
  <View style={styles.container}>
    {mostPopular && (
       <View style={styles.mostPopularSash}>
         <Text style={styles.mostPopularText}>Most</Text>
         <Text style={styles.mostPopularText}>Popular</Text>
       </View>
     )}
     <View style={styles.contentContainer}>
       <View style={styles.textContainer}>
         <Text style={styles.amountText}>£{amount}</Text>
         <Text style={styles.bonusGemsText}>+{gemsBonus} NGems Bonus</Text>
       </View>
       <Button
         text="Deposit"
         backgroundColor={Colours.primary}
         fontWeight="400"
         fontColour={Colours.white}
         fontSize={14}
         style={{marginBottom: 0, height: 35, marginTop: 10}}
         onPress={() => setModalVisible(true)}
       />
     </View>
  </View>
</View>
```

Credit to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67140055/13740590

Answer (score -1):

In iOS you can play with the zIndex

You can create a prop or a state that tells you which one is active.

For instance,

```
<View style={{zIndex:2}}>
{data.map(item => <CustomComp active={item.active} /> )}
</View>
```

In customcomp, you can set the parent style such as

```
style={{ props.active ? 3 : 1 }}
```

Make sure you have assign the zIndex to the container view

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but as I said I have tried to use zIndex with no success..

Comment: It would seem `zIndex` is ignored if it is applied to an element inside a container with `overflow: 'hidden`